# Flutter: How to secure completion of function before build function

Tags: flutter

I am writing a camera page in **TabBarView** and try to set up the camera controller using a function **_obtainCamera()** before running the build function that consists of a **FutureBuilder**.

The problem is that it seems **FutureBuilder** builds before **_obtainCamera()** completes, and the snapshot is always on the loading screen forever.

The weird thing is that, if I delete **_obtainCamera()** from my code, paste it once again and perform a hot reload, the view of the camera comes out. I don't sure If I have set the FutureBuilder in the wrong way or what? I think it is the problem of the order of execution but I don't know how to secure a function to be complete before **build()**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _obtainCamera();
  }

  Future<void> _obtainCamera() async {
    _cameraList = await availableCameras();
    firstCamera = await _cameraList.first;
    _controller = CameraController(
      firstCamera,
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }
...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<void>(
          future: _initializeControllerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
              debugPrint('done');
              return CameraPreview(_controller);
            } else {
              // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
              debugPrint('not done');
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () {},
      )
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem here because you call the init balue of controller instead of calling your future,
So you see this is wrong need

To solve this problem you can do 2 thing

1- modify your Future and using it directly in FutureBuilder

Or

2- call your Future In InitState for  setting your controller before building the widget

Besure you add await with async in initState

If it doesn't work use didChangeDependances

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code with this;

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();      
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
        _obtainCamera();  
      },
    );
  }
```